# Jacoco - ignore MyClass.1

Tags: java, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

How can *.1 classes be ignored in Jacoco coverage?

I have the following in my POM:

```
<execution>
  <id>JaCoco Coverage Enforcement</id>
  <phase>verify</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>check</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
  <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/MyClass.**</exclude>
  </excludes>
  <rules>
    ...
  </rules>
</execution>
```

However, I get the following error message:

> [WARNING] Rule violated for class com.mypackage.MyClass.1: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.85

**Update 12/19**

Here's what's in the folder structure:

```
$ find . -iname 'MyClass*class'
./target/classes/com/mypackage/MyClass$1.class
./target/classes/com/mypackage/MyClass.class
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you have on disk - file `MyClass.1.class` or file `1.class` in directory `MyClass`? Actually both look weird in case of plain Java. I'm guessing that you use some bytecode generation tool that generates such classes?

Comment: I added the disk data above.  I'm actually not doing anything too funky and the project is a pretty simple Spring Boot app running under Java 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Exclusion pattern for `verify` goal](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html#excludes) can be `**/MyClass$**` if you want to exclude only file `MyClass$1.class` (note the dollar sign in place, where you had the dot). If you want to exclude both `MyClass.class` and `MyClass$1.class`, then pattern can be `**/MyClass**`.